# How do i write a cleaner date picker input for SimpleForm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I love the `simple_form` gem for rails but i dont like this line of code:

```
<%= f.input :deadline, :as => :string, :input_html => { :class => 'date_picker' } %>
```

I would like to write:

```
<%= f.input :deadline, :as => :date_picker %>
```

or even over write the `:date` / `:datetime` matchers completely.

But i dont really want to write a whole `custom_simple_form`

I think it must be possible...

Please help thanks

Comment: I stumbled on a similar problem and found this answer very useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075404/how-can-i-generate-inputtype-date-with-simple-form
Hope it helps

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to define a new `DatePickerInput` class.

```
module SimpleForm
  module Inputs
    class DatePickerInput < Base
      def input
        @builder.text_field(attribute_name,input_html_options)
      end    
    end
  end
end
```

And you can now write

```
<%= f.input :deadline, :as => :date_picker %>
```

Off course you also need

```
 $("input.date_picker").datepicker();
```

in `application.js`

This is very useful to localize dates. Look at this:

```
module SimpleForm
  module Inputs
    class DatePickerInput < Base
      def input
        @builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options.merge(datepicker_options(object.send(attribute_name))))
      end

      def datepicker_options(value = nil)
        datepicker_options = {:value => value.nil?? nil : I18n.localize(value)}
      end

    end
  end
end
```

You have now a localized date in the text field!

**Update: a cleaner way to do the same**

```
module SimpleForm
  module Inputs
    class DatePickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
      def input_html_options
        value = object.send(attribute_name)
        options = {
          value: value.nil?? nil : I18n.localize(value),
          data: { behaviour: 'datepicker' }  # for example
        }
        # add all html option you need...
        super.merge options
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Inherit from `SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput` (as @kikito said) and add some html options.
If you need also a specific class you can add something like

```
def input_html_classes
  super.push('date_picker')
end
```

Comment: Great answer, worked perfectly. Couple of extra points. The 5th line of the custom input code should be `@builder.text_field(attribute_name, :class => 'date_picker')'. And this class needs to go into the file app/inputs/date_picker_input.rb.

Comment: See my answer below if you are using simple_form 2.x

Comment: Thanks. A small misspell, there are two `class` in your updated code

Comment: Hello I have built a small Gem using this example to use SimpleForm with jQueryUI datepicker: https://rubygems.org/gems/simple-form-datepicker

Comment: I'm using rails 4, where do I add the `DatePickerInput` class?

Answer (score 42):

The answers here seem a bit out of date if you are using simple_form 2.0.

I've been fighting with this for a while and was able to concoct this; it uses inheritance (notice that it is a subclass of `StringInput`, not `Base`), supports i18n and adds the `datepicker` css class in a more clean way, IMHO.

```
# app/inputs/date_picker_input.rb

class DatePickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput 
  def input                    
    value = input_html_options[:value]
    value ||= object.send(attribute_name) if object.respond_to? attribute_name
    input_html_options[:value] ||= I18n.localize(value) if value.present?
    input_html_classes << "datepicker"

    super # leave StringInput do the real rendering
  end
end
```

The usage is like above:

```
<%= f.input :deadline, :as => :date_picker %>
```

And the javascript remains the same:

```
$("input.date_picker").datepicker();
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. My date gets formatted like this "mer 06 nov 2013, 00:00:00 +0000". I don't know why.

Comment: @AgostinoX your locale must be French. The `I18n.localize` method uses the `time.formats.default` key to format dates. See https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/fr.yml#L66

Comment: If localization not working correclty add options to javascript.
`$("input.date_picker").datepicker({format: 'dd.mm.yyyy'});`

Answer (score 8):

Based on @kikito's answer, I did this to get a native datepicker (i.e. no special JS classes).

**config/initializers/simple_form_datepicker.rb**

```
class SimpleForm::Inputs::DatepickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput 
  def input                    
    input_html_options[:type] = "date"
    super
  end
end
```

Then used it like:

```
f.input :paid_on, as: :datepicker
```

Note that if you also have a **simple_form_bootstrap3.rb** initializer or similar, like we did, you should:

1. add `DatepickerInput` to its list of inputs
2. make sure the `simple_form_bootstrap3.rb` (or similar) initializer loads *after* `simple_form_datepicker.rb`, so that the `DatepickerInput` class is available. Do that by e.g. renaming the datepicker initializer to `simple_form_0_datepicker.rb`.

Comment: this works great and does not require any gems or external plugins, since it utilizes modern browsers capabilities of displaying built in datepickers. Recommended!

Answer (score 0):

An other option could also be to overwrite the default `DateTimeInput` helper, here's an example to be placed in `app/inputs/date_time_input.rb`

```
class DateTimeInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::DateTimeInput
  def input
    add_autocomplete!
    @builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options.merge(datetime_options(object.send(attribute_name))))
  end

  def label_target
    attribute_name
  end

  private

    def datetime_options(value = nil)
      return {} if value.nil?

      current_locale = I18n.locale
      I18n.locale = :en

      result = []
      result.push(I18n.localize(value, { :format => "%a %d %b %Y" })) if input_type =~ /date/
      if input_type =~ /time/
        hours_format = options[:"24hours"] ? "%H:%M" : "%I:%M %p"
        result.push(I18n.localize(value, { :format => hours_format }))
      end

      I18n.locale = current_locale

      { :value => result.join(', ').html_safe }
    end

    def has_required?
      options[:required]
    end

    def add_autocomplete!
      input_html_options[:autocomplete] ||= 'off'
    end
end
```

Please notice than while using this method makes it a drop feature for your forms, it might also break with future versions of simple_form.

***Notice about localized dates**: As far as I know Ruby interprets dates following only a few formats, you might want to be careful before localizing them and make sure Ruby can handle them.
An attempt to better localization support on the Ruby Date parsing as been started at https://github.com/ZenCocoon/I18n-date-parser, yet, this is not working.*

Answer (score -1):

In new formtastic previews answers doesn't work. See http://justinfrench.com/notebook/formtastic-2-preview-custom-inputs
Here is a simple working example (save to app/inputs/date_picker_input.rb):

```
class DatePickerInput < Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput
  def input_html_options
    {
      :class => 'date_picker',
    }.merge(super).merge({
      :size => '11'
    })
  end
end
```

Create a file app/assets/javascripts/date_picker.js with content:

```
$(function() {
  $("input#.date_picker").datepicker();
});
```

You also need to load jquery-ui. To do so, insert to app/assets/javascripts/application.js line:

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

or simply use CDN eg:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
```

Stylesheets for jquery-ui coul be inclded  http://babinho.net/2011/10/rails-3-1-jquery-ui/ or
from CDN:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" %>
```

Comment: thanks @LukasSvoboda but the question was for simple form not formtastic