# Simple form. How to override input to be text_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, date, simple-form

I am using simple_form gem and I need to change the type of "created_at" field from input to text_field (in order to use this field with jQuery date picker). Is it possible?

```
as: :string
```

is not suitable answer since it is not working with jQuery.datepicker

Comment: it's kina a diplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007785/how-do-i-write-a-cleaner-date-picker-input-for-simpleform

Comment: Thanks, rik.vanmechelen. It is what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is needed to create specific DatePickerInput class in app/inputs/date_picker.rb

```
app/inputs/date_picker.rb

class DatePickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput 
  def input                    
    value = object.send(attribute_name) if object.respond_to? attribute_name
    input_html_options[:value] ||= I18n.localize(value) if value.present?
    input_html_classes << "datepicker"

    super # leave StringInput do the real rendering
  end
end
```

javascript

```
jQuery -> 
 $('input.date_picker').datepicker()
```

in form just add the following line

```
    = f.input :due, as: :date_picker
```

This thread solved my problem [How do i write a cleaner date picker input for SimpleForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007785/how-do-i-write-a-cleaner-date-picker-input-for-simpleform) thanks to rio