# Add datepicker with rails 3.2.11, simple_form and bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I am trying to implement datepicker in my simple_form much as has been covered here: [How do i write a cleaner date picker input for SimpleForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007785/how-do-i-write-a-cleaner-date-picker-input-for-simpleform/5079761#5079761)

I create the custom class:

```
# app/inputs/date_picker_input.rb
class DatePickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
....
end
```

I then add: `$("input.date_picker").datepicker();

at the bottom of application.js and use the code:

```
<%= f.input :deadline, :as => :date_picker %>
```

However, a datepicker is not activated, nor is an error thrown. Could this be an issue with me not understanding the asset pipeline correctly? My application.js also contains:
    //= require jquery.ui.datepicker.min

I also use the datepicker on a separate page in my application that does not use simple_form, so datepicker by itself is working.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure datepicker is called in your JavaScript (change datepicker class if it is different in your form):

```
$(function() {
  $('input.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Also you can check
[How do i write a cleaner date picker input for SimpleForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007785/how-do-i-write-a-cleaner-date-picker-input-for-simpleform)
or https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/75#issuecomment-448362

Comment: Thanks, I tried using your suggestion of input.ui-datepicker but it still wasn't working. I think it started working when I kept your js code but changed it back to input.datepicker:
`$(function() {
  `$('input.ui-datepicker').datepicker();
`});

whereas previously I just had `$("input.date_picker").datepicker();
Could the js code have done the trick?

Either way, thank you so much for helping me get this sorted. I'm still kind of new to stackoverflow, do you need to update your answer to remove the .ui- for me to mark as correct?