# Datepicker won't Display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, datepicker

I have a Rails project using simple_form and I can't seem to get the date picker to work (using the Bootstrap Datepicker gem https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails.

I have tried what's been proposed in the following stack overflow posts:
[How do i write a cleaner date picker input for SimpleForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007785/how-do-i-write-a-cleaner-date-picker-input-for-simpleform)
[Add datepicker with rails 3.2.11, simple_form and bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452942/add-datepicker-with-rails-3-2-11-simple-form-and-bootstrap)
[Changes in the form are not saved to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405703/rails-simple-form-bootstrap-and-datepicker)

But, so far none of them have worked.

Here is my code:

In my View I have this:

```
<%= f.input :start_date, :input_html => {data: {behaviour: "datepicker"}}, :as => :string %>
```

I have added the following to Application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker

$(function() {
  $('input.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

I have added the following to Application.css

```
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

I've even tried putting the js code directly on the page and it still doesn't work.

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Thanks

Comment: Does the console log show any javascript errors ? Does the network tab show that the resource was correctly downloaded and its not a 404?

Comment: I'm seeing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL " for line #1 of my model. But, that's the default content so I'm not sure why that would happen. Status of all js files is "304 Not Modified" except for assets/bootstrap-datepicker/locales which is "(failed)". I'm only dealing with English in this project. Do I need to do something for that anyway?

Comment: You should try to remove all errors of your js console first as this might interrupt the execution of your datepicker code.

Comment: Cleared cache and reloaded, everything is loading fine now. Date Picker still not working

Answer (score 0):

Your function assigning the datepicker behavior searches for inputs with class 'datepicker'. Your inputs must have this class.

Use the following:

```
<%= f.input :start_date, :input_html => {class: 'datepicker', data: {behaviour: "datepicker"}}, :as => :string %>
```