# How can I generate input[type=date] with simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

When I do `f.input :start_date, as: :date` I get 3 select elements (day, month and year).

I can do `f.input :start_date, as: :string` to get `input[type=text]` element, but how can I generate `input[type=date]` element with simple_form?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should specify `html5` option:

```
f.input :start_date, as: :date, html5: true
```

[Here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#html-5-notice) is details.

Answer (score 15):

> HTML 5 date / time inputs are not generated by Simple Form by default, so using date, time or datetime will all generate select boxes using normal Rails helpers. We believe browsers are not totally ready for these yet, **but you can easily opt-in on a per-input basis by passing the html5 option**:
>
> `<%= f.input :expires_at, as: :date, html5: true %>`

Hopefully this piece of information found in [simple_form documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) will solve your problem.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this answer, as it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set that as the default defining a class that makes that as default:

```rb
# Use html5 date inputs by default, use html5: false to force
# the use of multiple selects
class DateTimeInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::DateTimeInput
  private

  def use_html5_inputs?
    input_options.fetch(:html5, true)
  end
end
```