# Simple_form & Nested attributes save blank model because of date attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

Model User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :experiences, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :experiences, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Model Experience

```
class Experience < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My input in the VIEW (_experience_fields_user.html)

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.input :start_date as: :date, discard_day: true, order: [:month, :year], start_year: Date.today.year , end_year: Date.today.year - 37  %>
</div>
```

=> So, that is displaying 2 fields "Month" and "Year"

If I submit my form, with a empty field the params are:

```
"expertise"=>"", "start_date(3i)"=>"1", "start_date(2i)"=>"", "start_date(1i)"=>""
```

My problem: "start_date(3i)"=>"1"

This params is not blank (it's represent the day value which is not displayed on the view), and not permit to completed the condition of nested attributes "reject_if: :all_blank"

There is a way to change the value of a day if month and year is blank?
Thx

Comment: you might get it working by replacing `as: :date` with `as: :string` in your form.

Comment: That change the behavior of the input and it's not the best way for a good user experience

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I've also had this issue in the past and am trying to remember how I solved it.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075404/how-can-i-generate-inputtype-date-with-simple-form) might be one option.

Comment: Interesting but in this case, i think that will be better to just remove the "discard_day: true" in the input :(

Comment: @Etienne Did you try remove `start_date(3i)` from permitted params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way:

I created a condition for test if another input is empty (in this case company_name)

In my model User:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :experiences, reject_if: :reject_xp, allow_destroy: true

def reject_xp(attributes)
   attributes['start_date(3i)'] == "1" && attributes['company_name'].blank?
end
```